# Split row value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have the following table in SQL Server

| id | vals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4, 5 |

I need a view where the values would be

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

I managed to split a comma and space -separated string to multiple rows like this (string to be separated is '1, 2'):

```sql
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT ( REPLACE('1, 2', ' ', ''), ',' )
```

However, I can't figure out how to apply this to the table so that I would get the id's to the view as well.

Comment: You know of course that the best solution is to store your data correctly normalised?

Comment: @DaleK The data is out of my control

Comment: use `CROSS APPLY()` . Actually there is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-split-comma-separated-value-string-in-a-column) in `STRING_SPLIT()` documentation

Comment: You can always push back as a dev and see if change is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `apply` clause

```
select * 
from
  Table t
  outer apply STRING_SPLIT(t.row,',') spl
```